# How to save Sent email in Webmail? my webhosting is Go daddy

Tags: php, phpmailer

Email is sending perfectly and receive by recipient but the problem is why sent mail is not saving on my roundcube sent mail. What wrong with my code? All help must be appreciated thank you in advance :)

I also try this but mine is not working https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/895

```
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
            use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

            require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
            require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
            require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

            $mail = new PHPMailer(); 

            $mail->IsSMTP();                
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;   
            $mail->SMTPSecure  = "tls"; //Secure conection
            $mail->Port       = 465;                    
            $mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; 
            
            $mail->Username   = "info@domain.com";   
            $mail->Password   = "******";            
        
            $mail->IsSendmail();  
        
            $mail->From       = "info@domain.com";
            $mail->FromName   = "domain.com";
        
            $mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");
            $mail->Subject  = "Inquiries";
            $mail->WordWrap   = 80; 
            
            
            $mail->IsHTML(true); 
            
            $mail->Body = $template;
            
            
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo "Message sent!";
     
      
            }
            
            
          //Function to call which uses the PHP imap_*() functions to save messages
            function save_mail($mail) {
                //You can change 'Sent Mail' to any other folder or tag
                //Use imap_getmailboxes($imapStream, '/imap/ssl') to retrieve a list of available folders or tags
                $path = "{mail.yourdomain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent";
                
                
                //Tell your server to open an IMAP connection using the same username and password as you used for SMTP
                $imapStream = imap_open($path, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
                $result = imap_append($imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
                imap_close($imapStream);
                echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this example?:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps#L82
It's using imap not smtp. There is a comment that shows how to save the email in the sent items folder.

Comment: Yes but they using gmail mine is roundcube

Comment: I Thinks there's a problem with my `save_mail`

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's Roundcube – both will be connecting to an IMAP server in the same way. The thing that is likely to be different is the paths and names of your mailboxes, which you can find out by using the `imap_getmailboxes` function, exactly as the snippet in your code suggests; It helps to read what is in front of you!

Comment: I got it! Haha I forgot to execute the function OMG.. btw I appreciate y'all :)

Answer (score 0):

$path = "{mail.yourdomain.com:993/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX";

$path = "{mail.yourdomain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";

Comment: still not working

Comment: Can you enhance your answer to include why your snippet will work?

Comment: That setting has nothing to do with IMAP connections.

Comment: sorry ,I read it wrong.
try 
$path = "{mail.yourdomain.com:993/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
or 
$path = "{mail.yourdomain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to reflect your changes. Don't count on comments. They are less visible and can be easily deleted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).